# How do I deal with many variables per triangle in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm working with OpenGL and am not totally happy with the standard method of passing values PER TRIANGLE (or in my case, quads) that need to make it to the fragment shader, i.e., assign them to each vertex of the primitive and pass them through the vertex shader to presumably be unnecessarily interpolated (unless using the "flat" directive) in the fragment shader (so in other words, non-varying per fragment).

Is there some way to store a value PER triangle (or quad) that needs to be accessed in the fragment shader in such a way that you don't need redundant copies of it per vertex? Is so, is this way better than the likely overhead of 3x (or 4x) the data moving code CPU side?

I am aware of using geometry shaders to spread the values out to new vertices, but I heard geometry shaders are terribly slow on non up to date hardware. Is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one element in the vertex array for rendering multiple vertices. It's called *instanced vertex attributes*.

Comment: You fixed your answer.

Comment: @snb Did you think the previous edit was suggesting a different solution? In my mind, I was suggesting the same thing before. :)

Comment: yes, it looked like you were talking about something different.

Comment: @snb Actually I just googled, and looks like I was suggesting an incorrect function. ._.

Comment: no, you were closer before, look at [this](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing).   You want to use the divider or else you wont be able to use the attribute per instance.  Also another thing  that threw me off is you said "this method couldn't speed up rendering" when instancing *does* speed up rendering...  you send one command instead of 10000.

Comment: @snb But `glVertexAttribDivisor` allows one attribute value per *instance*, not per triangle. One triangle per instance would be silly. You're correct about performance, edited that.

Comment: Op states: "PER triangle (or quad)", they can draw each triangle or quad individually instanced, but regardless, there is not enough information for any one to figure out what to do with this.  I'm not even sure what you are talking about any more.

Answer (score 6):

OpenGL fragment language supports the [`gl_PrimitiveID`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/gl_PrimitiveID.xhtml) input variable, which will be the index of the primitive for the currently processed fragment (starting at 0 for each draw call). This can be used as an index into some data store which holds per-primitive data.

Depending on the amount of data that you will need per primitive, and the number of primitives in total, different options are available. For a small number of primitives, you could just set up a uniform array and index into that.

For a reasonably high number of primitives, I would suggest using a [texture buffer object (TBO)](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_buffer_object.txt). This is basically an ordinary buffer object, which can be accessed read-only at random locations via the [`texelFetch`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/texelFetch.xhtml) GLSL operation. Note that TBOs are not really textures, they only reuse the existing texture object interface. Internally, it is still a data fetch from a buffer object, and it is very efficient with none of the overhead of the texture pipeline.

The only issue with this approach is that you cannot easily mix different data types. You have to define a base data type for your TBO, and every fetch will get you the data in that format. If you just need some floats/vectors per primitive, this is not a problem at all. If you e.g. need some ints and some floats per primitive, you could either use different TBOs, one for each type, or with modern GLSL (>=3.30), you could use an integer type for the TBO and reinterpret the integer bits as floating point with [`intBitsToFloat()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/intBitsToFloat.xhtml), so you can get around that limitation, too.

Comment: Are you suggesting then that I would index into the TBO with gl_PrimitiveID?

Comment: @ChristopherBrown: yes. YOu will need of course some factor since you probably need more than one "element" per primitive (or maybe not), so don't want to directly use the `gl_PrimitiveID` as the texcoord.